# Django mysql connectio No module named mysql.base

Tags: mysql, django, installation

I try to connect MySQL from django application serverd in AWS but it raises an interesting error: **Error was: No module named mysql.base**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'try',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'pwd',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

MySQLdb is already installed. `import MySQLdb` runs in python command line.

I can connect MySQL. I have installed it by sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev

I am really stuck with this error. Could you help to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Does `python manage.py dbshell` work? How about `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you haven't installed mysql for python.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.3

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: MySQLdb is already installed. import MySQLdb doesn't raise any error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with your Python PATH. Make sure the python-mysql db driver is in the PATH.